# Считывание только цифр из txt файла

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть txt файл в котором находятся даты рождения определенных лиц.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно извлечь только даты рождения, то есть цифры в формате 'y.m.d', но почему в списке data все данные представлены в виде 'y.m', '.d'? как исправить, подскажите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как Вы видите, все примеры без регулярок, как говорится в известном меме: если Вы решили решить проблему с помощью регулярных выражений - то у Вас 2 проблемы. xD

```
in_str = '''
А Б 2000.1.9
В Г 2001.6.7
Д Е 2000.7.5
Ж З 2005.9.4
И К 1999.6.4
''';

# in_list содержит строки из файла, для удобства я сделал через in_str
in_list = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', in_str.split("\n"))); 

out_list = [];
for string in in_list:
    item = string.split(' ')[2].split('.');
    out_list.append(item);

print(out_list);
```

Вывод:

```
[['2000', '1', '9'], ['2001', '6', '7'], ['2000', '7', '5'], ['2005', '9', '4'], ['1999', '6', '4']]
```

**UPD0:**
Чтобы `list` содержал **числа** дат, а не **строки**, можно сделать так:

```
in_str = '''
А Б 2000.1.9
В Г 2001.6.7
Д Е 2000.7.5
Ж З 2005.9.4
И К 1999.6.4
''';

# in_list содержит строки из файла, для удобства я сделал через in_str
in_list = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', in_str.split("\n"))); 

out_list = [];
for string in in_list:
    item = list(map(int, string.split(' ')[2].split('.')));
    out_list.append(item);

print(out_list);
```

Вывод:

```
[[2000, 1, 9], [2001, 6, 7], [2000, 7, 5], [2005, 9, 4], [1999, 6, 4]]
```

**UPD1:**
Кажется я не совсем понял, что именно нужно, если нужен просто список дат в виде строк можно так:

```
in_str = '''
А Б 2000.1.9
В Г 2001.6.7
Д Е 2000.7.5
Ж З 2005.9.4
И К 1999.6.4
''';

# in_list содержит строки из файла, для удобства я сделал через in_str
in_list = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', in_str.split("\n"))); 

out_list = [];
for string in in_list:
    item = string.split(' ')[2];
    out_list.append(item);

print(out_list);
```

Вывод:

```
['2000.1.9', '2001.6.7', '2000.7.5', '2005.9.4', '1999.6.4']
```